# Unable to prepare a bootable usb stick with 15.04 in Trusty

Tags: live-usb, startup-disk-creator

I cannot do bootable usb stick in Ubuntu 15.04 with "startup disk creator". After copying files it says: "system policy prevents installing the bootloader". This is odd because I was able to do this somehow in Ubuntu 14.04.

Comment: Did you check the md5sum of your downloaded iso on https://help.ubuntu.com/community/ubuntuHashes ?

Comment: Hi @Fabby, yes I did. File is correct.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a bug. An incredible one....

In the [release notes of 15.10 beta](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/WilyWerewolf/ReleaseNotes), you can read:

> Due to changes in syslinux, it is not currently possible to use
>   usb-creator from 14.04 and earlier releases to write USB images for
>   15.04; we believe that it is also not possible to use usb-creator from a 15.04 system to write USB images for earlier releases. For now the
>   workaround is to use a matching release of Ubuntu to write the images,
>   but we intend to issue updates soon to work around this
>   incompatibility.

See the bug here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/bugs/1325801

So it seems that, for the time being, you need 15.04 or later to build a bootable USB for 15.04 or later. Catch 22...

So to work around this issue now: create an old-fashioned DVD or 
try to use the `mkusb` method explained in  https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromUSBStick .

Comment: @Fabby, lots of laptop now come without a DVD, so I think it's better to leave the link to the mkusb solution too

Comment: True...  Sorry!  For an old fart like me who goes for a 17" desktop replacement laptop it's easy to forget some people like 10" no-nothing machines...  Thanks for keeping the DVD sentence, though, will leave a comment next time!  **;-)**

Comment: mkusb did work :-)

Answer (score 0):

You need super user rights to do this. If you're using an adimn account, you'll be asked for your password. If you're a standard user / guest user, there is no way you can install a bootloader.